# Excel VBA Autofilter date/time >=12 hours

Tags: excel, vba, filter, excel-formula, autofilter

I am trying to filter data that is for an entire week by only the past 12 hours. The columns for my data has has a separate date column and time.[image]

So because of this I have it only searching from previous day and current.

The issue I am having is that if I run the report at 8am then the time frame is 8pm-8am. But because the date goes to the previous day it also pulls from 12am-8am from that day.

Here is the VBA code.

(DataY1 is the current date minus 12 hours)

```
Sub Filer_Calc()
'
' Filer_Calc Macro
' filter then calc
'

'
Loading.Show False
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    Sheets("Megamation Data").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$J$250").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
    ">=" & Format(TimeValue(Now) - (12 / 24), "hh:mm:ss AM/PM"), _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$J$250").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
    ">=" & Format(Range("Data!Y1"), "m/dd/yy"), _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Sheets("Rate Estimator").Select
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Loading.Hide
End Sub
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried multiple ways to get this filter function to work properly... No luck.

Comment: Instead of a macro, how about using a helper column and filter on that?

Comment: This might seem silly... But what would be the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper column with the following formula:

```
=IF(NOW()-B18-A18<=0.5,"Within 12 hours","")
```

[image]

Filter on the helper column:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Then please mark the answer as correct -- we're not doing this for free, you know :)